# Erro na configuração de arquivo properties

Tags: java, jsf

Estou tentando configurar um arquivo properties. Segui uns tutoriais mas sem sucesso. Estou com o seguinte erro:

> Caused by: java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for
>   base name src.main.resources.properties.mensagens, locale pt

Meu arquivo faces-config está assim:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<faces-config xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_2.xsd"
    version="2.2">
    <application>
        <locale-config>
            <default-locale>pt</default-locale>
            <!-- <supported-locale>en</supported-locale> -->
        </locale-config>
        <resource-bundle>
            <base-name>src.main.resources.properties.mensagens</base-name>
            <var>msg</var>
        </resource-bundle>
    </application>
</faces-config>
```

Alguém sabe como resolvo isso?

Comment: <!-- <supported-locale>en</supported-locale> --> <!-- <supported-locale>pt</supported-locale> --> pode ser algo por aqui naum, num manjo de java, mas pelo erro pode ser um caminho

Comment: <p> The "default-locale" element declares the default locale
        for this application instance.</p>
        
        <p>It must be specified as :language:[_:country:[_:variant:]]
        without the colons, for example "ja_JP_SJIS".  The
        separators between the segments may be '-' or '_'.</p>    outro caminho http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/cant-find-bundle-for-base-name-xxx-locale-en_us/

Comment: Não resolveu :(

Comment: Putz é o máximo que pude ajudar..GL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depois de quebrar bastante a cabeça e testando aqui e ali, deixei no meu faces-config.xml o trecho do caminho do arquivo assim:

```
<base-name>properties.mensagens</base-name>
```

Não precisou passar o nome todo.